# how to load a partial view ona selector using jquery?

Tags: model-view-controller

```
 var uri="@Url.Content("/Views/Shared/_LogOnPartial")";

        $("#logindisplay").load(uri);
```

it give me error

```
Files with leading underscores ("_") cannot be served.
```

why the url don't work.

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code to load Partial Views in ~/Views/Shared/ Folder.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            $("#btnclick").click(function () {
                var uri = '@Url.Content("_LogOnPartial")';
                $("#logindisplay").load(uri);
            });
        });
</script>
```

HTML is,

```
<input type="button" id="btnclick" value="Load View" />

<div id="logindisplay">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use 
    "@Html.Partial("/Views/Shared/_LogOnPartial)

to load partial instead of @Url.Content("/Views/Shared/_LogOnPartial")

best practice is to define path for partials, Layouts & views earlier
in App_Start/RouteConfig write method like below
            public static void RegisterViewEngines(ICollection engines)
        {
            /* 
             * {0} = view name
             * {1} = controller name
            */
            engines.Clear();

```
        engines.Add(new RazorViewEngine
        {
            ViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/{0}.cshtml" },
            MasterLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/Shared/{0}.cshtml" },
            PartialViewLocationFormats = new[] { "~/Views/Partial/{0}.cshtml" }
        });
    }
```

then execute it in Globa.asax like
    RouteConfig.RegisterViewEngines(ViewEngines.Engines);

then you can easily call partial like this

```
@Html.Partial("_LogOnPartial");
```